# Passing a Scala type to a function

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement [basically the same thing that is discussed here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F7654039%2Fpassing-type-information-to-function-in-scala&ei=uhFYVcGpMsr5yQS1uIGAAw&usg=AFQjCNFvTCs1WQ6fYcS8_ft_Ux_TY-ok4Q&bvm=bv.93564037,d.aWw), but in my specific situation, it's not working.

Currently I have a function that validates a JSON response from our server. The problem is, it has the JSON type hardcoded into the method:

```
    def fakeRequest[A: Writes](target: () => Call, requestObject: A): Any = {
        route(FakeRequest(target()).withJsonBody(Json.toJson(requestObject))) match {
            // ... stuff happens
            Json.parse(contentAsString(response)).validate[GPInviteResponse]
                                                           ^
```

Note the hardcoded **GPInviteResponse** type.

So, to make this a totally generic and reusable method, it would be great to pass in the type that is being validated.

I tried this:

```
    def fakeRequest[A: Writes, B](target: () => Call, requestObject: A, responseType: B): Any = {
        route(FakeRequest(target()).withJsonBody(Json.toJson(requestObject))) match {
            // ... stuff happens
            Json.parse(contentAsString(response)).validate[B]
                                                           ^
```

That almost works, but I get a `No Json deserializer found for type B.` Makes sense, so I changed it to:

```
    def fakeRequest[A: Writes, B: Reads](target: () => Call, requestObject: A, responseType: B): Any = {
```

But, now I get `No Json deserializer found for type controllers.GPInviteResponse.type.` So the question is: Is it possible to pass a type like this (or is there some other magic to make it work)?

**There is** a deserializer defined for the type... I've re-read it half a dozen times to make sure there's no typo:

```
case class GPInviteResponse(inviteSent: Boolean, URL: Option[String], error: Option[GPRequestError] = None) {
    def this(error: GPRequestError) = this(false, None, Option(error))
}

object GPInviteResponse {
    implicit val readsInviteResponse = Json.reads[GPInviteResponse]
    implicit val writesInviteResponse = Json.writes[GPInviteResponse]
}
```

**Edit**

Included below is a simplified test case that demonstrates the problem. At the moment, this won't compile (error is shown below). I think I understand why it won't work (vaguely) but I have no idea regarding a solution. My theory as to why it won't work: While the provided type `GPInviteRequest` does have an implicit Reads/Writes method, Scala cannot make the connection that an instance `B` is actually a `GPInviteRequest` so it concludes that `B` does not have Reads/Writes.

```
case class GPInviteResponse(inviteSent: Boolean)
object GPInviteResponse {
    implicit val readsInviteResponse = Json.reads[GPInviteResponse]
    implicit val writesInviteResponse = Json.writes[GPInviteResponse]
}
class TestInviteServices extends PlaySpecification {
    "try to validate a type" in {
        tryToValidate(GPInviteRequest(true))
    }
    def tryToValidate[B: Reads, Writes](i: B) = {
        val json = Json.toJson(i).toString
        Json.parse(json).validate[B].isSuccess must beTrue
    }
}
```

The above test yields:

> [error]
>   /Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server-2/project/glimpulse-server/test/application/TestInviteServices.scala:46:
>   No Json serializer found for type B. Try to implement an implicit
>   Writes or Format for this type. [error]       val json =
>   Json.toJson(i).toString [error]                             ^ [error]
>   /Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server-2/project/glimpulse-server/test/application/TestInviteServices.scala:133:
>   No Json deserializer found for type controllers.GPInviteResponse.type.
>   Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type. [error]
>             fakeRequest(controllers.routes.GPInviteService.invite, i,
>   GPInviteResponse) match { [error]                        ^

Comment: Can you give a minimal example that compiles and exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message:

> No Json serializer found for type B. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

In this function, how is the `toJson` method supposed to know how to serialize your type B?

```
   def tryToValidate[B: Reads, Writes](i: B) = {
        val json = Json.toJson(i).toString
        Json.parse(json).validate[B].isSuccess must beTrue
    }
```

You haven't pulled in a writer/reader into scope, the compiler doesn't know where to look for one and that's why it's telling you to implement one. Here's a quick solution

```
case class GPInviteResponse(inviteSent: Boolean)
object GPInviteResponse {
  implicit val format = Json.format[GPInviteResponse]
}

def tryToValidate[B](i: B)(implicit format: Format[B]) = {
  val json = Json.toJson(i).toString
  Json.parse(json).validate[B]
}
```

Note: using the `format` method is equivalent to defining both a `reads` and `writes`.

Now, there is an implicit formatter for `B` in scope, so the compiler knows where to find it and injects it into the `validate` method which takes a `reader` implicitly:

```
// From play.api.libs.json

def validate[T](implicit rds: Reads[T]): JsResult[T] = rds.reads(this)
```

**Edit**

You can add type parameters to your function and then reference them in the `validate[T]` method, like so:

```
// Define another case class to use in the example
case class Foo(bar: String)
object Foo {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Foo]
}

def tryToValidate[B, C](implicit f1: Format[B], f2: Format[C]) = {

  val j1 = """{"inviteSent":true}"""
  val j2 = """{"bar":"foobar"}""" // 

  Json.parse(j1).validate[B]
  Json.parse(j2).validate[C]
}

// Example call
tryToValidate[GPInviteResponse, Foo]
```

Comment: I didn't realize format() was basically reads/writes together, thanks. This is a great answer... but, I'm having trouble applying it to the "real world" case, which is slightly more complicated. This function signature: `def fakeRequest[A, B](target: () => Call, request: A, response: B)(implicit f1: Format[A], f2: Format[B])` is giving the same error as before ("No Json formatter found for GPInviteResponse.type"). It seems adding the second type (separating the request and response types) has complicated it.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now: In the example, an instance is passed in. In my "real world" case, I'm specifying a **type** (not an instance). Is there a way to pass the actual **type** (eg. `GPInviteRequest`) and not an instance?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way :

```
def tryToValidate[B](i: B)(implicit format : Format[B]) = {
        val json = Json.toJson(i).toString
        Json.parse(json).validate[B].isSuccess must beTrue
    }
```